# View Excel file using Activex Control

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, activex, activexobject

I want to view excel file in my windows application which I am trying to build using visual studio 2010.

How can I do this ?

Is there any excel activeX control for this.

Suggestion are warmly welcome....

Please Help

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you just in need of some editable table? Or are you trying to display some graphs? Requiring Excel to be installed is a huge dependency depending on the intended usage of your program.

Comment: No graphs. I want to display excel sheet through my application. I am not going to edit any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WebBrowser control to preview Excel file in Windows Forms application.

Samples:

- [How to Integrate Excel in a Windows
  Form Application using the WebBrowser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/Embedding_Excel.aspx)
- [How to use the WebBrowser control to open Office documents in Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304662)

Comment: It's a possible solution but not 100% failsafe: Depending on user settings the document might be offered for download or just open in a standalone instance of Excel as well.

Comment: Yep, but he can use Extended Web Browser control and have complete control over it: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/csEXWB.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Actually I found two techniques to do this:

1. **Use a Web Browser control:** And it is better to use AxWebBrowser because when you use 2007 and 2010 version of excel the ribbon can not be shown and using this control instead of WebBrowser is better to help solve this problem.
2. **Use SetParent Win32 API:** I think this is the better solution because it is more controllable. Fortunately the complete control implemented by this technique is published in CodePlex and it is here: [ExcelViewer](http://excelviewer.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion about ExcelViewer, but could you help me with one question about it because I'm a bit new in C#: I took the ExcelViewer library and connect it to my project. How can place  this component on my winForm? Thank you.

Comment: You have to add it to toolbox. Right click on the toolbox then select choose items then browse for library and add it to the toolbox. Then you can add it to your form. If you think my answer is correct mark it as correct answer.

Comment: Thank you. I have another one issue :-). I've added this component to my winForm. Open Excel file in it. But I can't do any selection (select cells) in this file. Do you know how fix this problem?

Comment: This was a bug that I have fixed it in win7. But now in Win8 I couldn't fix that! I have checked in a fix to codeplex. You can test if that will work for you or not.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it, but it's so pity that it doesn't work in win8

Comment: For those who still need a version that works on Win8.1/Win10 IE11. Take a look at this post http://alemiralles.blogspot.com.ar/2016/10/how-to-show-excel-files-inside-net.html

Comment: Hi @alisabzevari, I was trying to use your ExcelViewer control but I cannot see it in VBE toolbox. Any ideas? I've added the reference through "Tools\References" in VBE but I cannot see any ExcelViewer control when trying to add it to the toolbox (through right-click/Additional controls...). Any ideas?

Comment: The ExcelViewer link is dead.